# React: How to extract values from Modals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, modal-dialog, chakra-ui

I have a Chakra UI Modal which opens up onClick of a button. I want to be able to extract the values that a user puts into the inputs/radio buttons when they close the Modal. The Modal class and the Modal/Button render is shown below. Since the input and radio buttons are defined within the Modal class, is it possible to get their final values `onClose`?

**Modal.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
    Modal as ChakraModal,
    ModalOverlay,
    ModalContent,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalFooter,
    ModalBody,
    ModalCloseButton,
    RadioGroup,
    Stack,
    Radio,
    VStack
  } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import Button from './Button'
import Input from './Input'


type Props = { isOpen : boolean } & { onClose : () => void} & { label : string } 

const Modal = ({ label, isOpen, onClose, ...rest }: Props) => (
    <ChakraModal {...rest} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
      <ModalOverlay />
      <ModalContent>
        <ModalHeader>{label}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalCloseButton />
        <ModalBody>
          <VStack spacing={4}>
            <RadioGroup>
              <Stack direction="row">
                <Radio value="1">Annually</Radio>
                <Radio value="2">Semi-Annual</Radio>
                <Radio value="3">Quarterly</Radio>
                <Radio value="4">Monthly</Radio>
              </Stack>
            </RadioGroup>
            <Input  
              label="Custom Interest rate"
              name="Custom Interest rate"
            />
          </VStack>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
            Save
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </ModalContent>
    </ChakraModal>
)

export default Modal
```

**Render**

```js
<Button onClick={onOpen}> Settings </Button>
<Modal 
  label="Custom Settings"
  isOpen={isOpen} 
  onClose={onClose}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably send a state as the modal's prop.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState();
<Modal 
  label="Custom Settings"
  isOpen={isOpen} 
  onClose={onClose}
  onChange={setState}
/>
```

To get the type of setState, hover over the variable and you can see the type definition.